# How can I set flex-basis when using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, flexbox, responsive-design

I am curious how to set flex-basis for items in flex box, which flex direction is set to column.

```
<div class='flex'>
    <div class='box1'>box</div>
    <div class='box2'>box</div>
</div>
```

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
   flex-basis: 70%;
}

.box2 {
 flex-basis: 30%
}
```

how to implement it in bootstrap

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter which direction your flex container has. Flex-basis is just a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

You do it just like you did. No library provides every functionality imaginable, especially when there's a variable that would make implementation very complex (such as an arbitrary size).

I do suggest a more semantic naming convention, though. Something like this aligns better with Bootstrap's model and best practice in general:

```
.flex-basis-30 {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.flex-basis-70 {
  flex-basis: 70%;
}
```

Also, use Bootstrap's [classes for flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#direction). No need to write your own. I've created a height class as well, in alignment with Bootstrap's [sizing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/sizing). However, it's often best to let your overall layout and content determine height rather than using fixed heights.

```
.h-100px {
  height: 100px;
}

<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100px">
  <div class="flex-basis-70">box</div>
  <div class="flex-basis-30">box</div>
</div>
```

I've built many Bootstrap sites over the last decade and a half, and every single one has had a custom stylesheet for a few things. Yours will too.